# How to get ending time last 1 hour data in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, mysqli, phpmyadmin

I have below table filed in varchar datatype, I want get the last one hour data from table time using mysql query
I have

**PHP**

```
$total = (double) $input * (double) $rate;
return number_format((double) $total, 2);
```

**Jquery**

```
total =  parseFloat(input) * parseFloat(rate);
return  total.toFixed(2);
```

**PHP**

```
$total = (double) $input * (double) $rate;
return number_format((double) $total, 2);
```

**Jquery**

```
total =  parseFloat(input) * parseFloat(rate);
return  total.toFixed(2);
```

Comment: Provide the table structure and some sample table data.

Comment: Please check image link https://i.stack.imgur.com/tZAD0.png   this field data type varchar format

Comment: Only one column in your table?

Comment: i need condition for this coloumn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the rows from your table with the `datetime` column value between current date and time and 1 hr before current time.

**Query**

```
select * from `your_table_name`
where `your_column_name` between date_add(now(), interval -1 hour) and now();
```

Answer (score 0):

Used below query.
**Note** your ColumName data type must be (datetime)

```
SELECT * FROM `tableName` WHERE 'ColumnName' BETWEEN (NOW() - INTERVAL 1 HOUR) AND NOW()
```